# how to remove Arabic hashtags?

Tags: java, regex, string, arabic, twitter4j

I am polling tweets from twitter using Twitter4j
and I am trying to filter hashtags from it after I take text from it
I turn it into strings now 
I have this String: "892698363371638784:RT @hikids_ksa: اللعبة خطيرة مرا ويبي لها مخ و تفكير و مهارة
متوفرة في #متجر_هاي_كيدز_الالكتروني .."

I want to remove متجر_هاي_كيدز_الالكتروني as it has Hashtag after it using java

the problem my code didn't work on this input:
"@kaskasomar هيدا بلا مخ متل متل غيرو بيخون الشعب اللبناني وبيتهمو بالارهاب بس لان رأيو بيختلف عن رأي الاخرين #سخيف"

the part سخيف wasn't removed for some reason
this is my method

```
static String removeHashtags(String in)
{
    in = in.replaceAll("#[A-Za-z]+","");//remove English hashtags
    in = in.replaceAll("[أ-ي]#+","");//remove Arabic hashtags that have # before it
    return in = in.replaceAll("#[أ-ي]+","");//remove Arabic hashtags that have # after it
}
```

Comment: in = in.replaceAll("[أ-ي]#+",""); --> shouldn't the *#* be before the square brackets?

Comment: shouldn't "[أ-ي]#+" be "[أ-ي]+#" ?

Comment: @tingr4y can you rewrite you expression please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove all hash tags in any language, you can write

```
in = in.replaceAll("#\\p{IsAlphabetic}+", "");
```

If you specifically want to remove Arabic hash tags, you can write

```
in = in.replaceAll("#\\p{IsArabic}+", "");
```

so you don't have to worry about building a regular expression with left-to-right and right-to-left parts.  This improves the readability of your code.

Comment: although your line helped me reduce the number of hashtags a lot I am getting this "RT @hikids_ksa: اللعبة خطيرة مرا ويبي لها مخ و تفكير و مهارة
متوفرة في #متجر_هاي_كيدز_الالكتروني .."

Comment: It looks like you want to match underscores as well as letters.  You could try `"#[\\p{IsAlphabetic}_]+"`.

Comment: it was very helpful , I have no Hashtags now still I want to know how to remove hashtags that have characters I might not have considered like ':' '?' '$' or does alphabet handle this

Comment: If you want to match any non-space character, you can just use `"#\\S+"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, in the second line, the `+` is applied to the hashtag, not the Arabic characters. Fixed version:

```
in = in.replaceAll("[أ-ي]+#","");
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below removes Arabic hashtags mixed with English characters and [0-9] using the Unicode

```
import re
text = "#مرحبا"
reg = r"#[0-9\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u066C\u0671-\u0674a-zA-Z_]+"
text = re.sub(reg, " ", text)
```

Example: [regexr.com/691cn](http://regexr.com/691cn)

Comment: This works if #عالم but doesn't remove if hashtag is:  عالم#

Comment: appreciate if you have any input here. especially for python

Comment: Hi. Depends if the text is LTR or RTL. If RTL, then you just move the # to end, and it will work. Something like r"[0-9\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u066C\u0671-\u0674a-zA-Z_]+#"

Comment: thank u. this worked for me,  re.sub(r\"[أ-ي]+#\",'', text)